# How do i check my object permissions in spring security acl instead of using hasPermission annotation

Tags: spring, spring-security, acl

Is there a way to check my class object permissions directly from my code instead of having the annotation model,

```
@PostAuthorize("hasPermission(returnObject, 'WRITE')")
public BaseData getSingle(Long id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're intending to use the ACL module, the expression is implemented in [`AclPermissionEvaluator`](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/acl/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/acls/AclPermissionEvaluator.java). So you can wire up an instance of that with an `AclService`, inject it into the classes that need it and call the `hasPermission` method directly.

Answer (score 1):

At-last after several tries i could achieve to get the solution, following is the code

acl-conf.xml

```
...
<bean class="org.springframework.security.acls.AclPermissionEvaluator" id="permissionEvaluator">
        <constructor-arg ref="aclService"/>
</bean>
...
```

samplecontroller.java

```
 @Autowired
    private PermissionEvaluator permissionEvaluator ;

    Permission permission = BasePermission.WRITE;
   permissionEvaluator.hasPermission(authentication,aclObject,permission);
....
```

Hope this is helpful.